# Laptop overheating even after installing thermald , tlp

Tags: overheating

I'm not a engineering student so i don't have much knowledge about Linux but i want to shift from windows to Linux hence I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 with windows 8. My laptop goes nuts after i boot linux, temp increases up to 89-91 c. I'm using thermald, tlp but no success.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'` terminal command.

Answer (score 0):

**Try installing nVidia drivers**

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-331 nvidia-settings nvidia-prime prime-indicator
```

and switch to Intel HD graphics. Hope it will help.

Comment: I am using nvidia-340 on ubuntu 16.04. So you can try with nvidia-340 instead of nvidia-331. I have noticed that newer drivers nvidia-35x and nvidia-36x have overheating issues on my nvidia 720m card.